# Passing docker parameters to lambda ECR containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way to pass the S3 key to the docker as a parameter.

setup:
On AWS lambda have a function to run a ECR docker container. The trigger is putobject on S3, this works. How to pass the S3 key to the container.

Saw other options to use run task, conainerOverrides, this requires a default cluster, so trying to run it directly with lambda without cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just run any Docker image on AWS Lambda, the software on the image has to implement the AWS Lambda function interface. When the Lambda function is invoked by S3 the S3 object key will be part of the `event` object passed to the Lambda function handler, just like with non-Docker Lambda functions.

See the [Lambda requirements for container images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-reqs) documentation.